# FLutter || Pick file using file picker and showing them in a listview.builder

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview

Created a function to pick file on onPressed() of Elevated Button, and pass the files to a new function openfiles() and then in open files function, I call a widget show() and pass the parameters to it. How to return in listView.
The default constructor takes an explicit List of children. This constructor is appropriate for list views with a small number of children because constructing the List requires doing work for every child that could possibly be displayed in the list view instead of just those children that are actually visible.

**pickFile class**

```dart
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final result =
                  await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple:true);
              if (result == null) return;
              openFiles(result.files);
            },
            child: const Text("pick file"),
          ),
        ),
        Text("data"),
      ],
    ),
  );
  }
     void openFiles(List<PlatformFile> files) {
     show(files: files);
      }
    }
```

**ListView in UI**

```dart
    import 'package:file_picker/src/platform_file.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    Widget show({
    List<PlatformFile>? files,
    }) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: files!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final file = files[index];
          return buildFile(file);
          }),
     );}
    Widget buildFile(PlatformFile file) {
    final kb = file.size / 1024;
    final mb = kb / 1024;
    final size =
      (mb >= 1) ? '${mb.toStringAsFixed(2)} MB' : '${kb.toStringAsFixed(2)} KB';
    return Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () => null,
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: (file.extension == 'jpg' || file.extension == 'png')
              ? Image.file(
                  File(file.path.toString()),
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                )
              : Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                ),
          title: Text('${file.name}'),
          subtitle: Text('${file.extension}'),
          trailing: Text(
            '$size',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
        ),
      ),
     ),
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `show()` function is returning a Widget so you have to put it somewhere in the widget tree.

So first I would get rid of your `openFiles()` function, because it doesn't really have a purpose. Then initialize a List in your `_pickFileState` class:

```dart
List<PlatformFile> files = [] //ANOTHER EDIT HERE,
```

Then you insert you widget returned by `show()` into widget tree:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Container(), //your Container here
    show(files: files), //here you insert your List
  ],
),
```

And lastly when you change your function in 'onPressed' method:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
    if (result == null) return;
    files = result.files; //EDIT: THIS PROBABLY CAUSED YOU AN ERROR
    setState((){});
  },
)
```

You use `setState()` to rebuild your Widget.

Comment: i did an edit to my answer, check it if that is what caused your problem

Comment: By initializing `List<PlatformFile>?` with ? in your `show()` function you allow to be null, but you never do anything to handle it if it is null, and then you use `files!` which causes you an error. So next time if you initialize it with ? handle the case when it is going to be null, or just don't initialize it with ?. I edited the code, so `files` will never be null.

Comment: If we don't use null it gives us an error: List<PlatformFile> files
Non-nullable instance field 'files' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'.dartnot_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field.

Comment: `List<PlatformFile> files = [];` you sure you wrote exactly like that, because this initializes it

Comment: Code is working, but the list is not updating new items on the list. I want to add multiple files and show them all.

Answer (score 0):

You must setState your widget after fetching files. return value of `show` is being ignored. (method `show(files: files);` is not attached to flutter's widget tree.)